# Eclipse scala.object cannot be resolved

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

I am trying to write Kafka producer and consumer code in Java using Eclipse. 
I am have downloaded the Kafka jar file and loaded as external Jar file. And it solved the dependency problem.

However, there is always a unresolved error and the message looks like below:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The type scala.Product cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
- The type scala.Serializable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class 
 files
```

I really don't know what is going on and how to fix that error. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**UPDATED 4/26/2018**

It appears that you need to have the *Scala* runtime library in your *Eclipse* project's classpath.

If you're using *Maven* (or some other repository-based build tool—highly recommended), then adding *Kafka* as a dependency should cause it to automatically download the corresponding *Scala* runtime library and include it on your project's classpath. For example,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

will cause *Maven* to download version 2.12.4 of the *Scala* runtime library.

Otherwise, you can install Scala (see http://scala-lang.org/) and add the installed scala-library.jar to your project's classpath manually. However, you should note that *Scala* minor releases (2.10.x, 2.11.x, 2.12.x, etc.) are not binary compatible with each other, so you should download the most recent bug-fix version of the minor release used to build your version of *Kafka*. (This minor version is appended to the name of the *Kafka* artifact, e.g. kafka_2.12 requires a *Scala* 2.12.x runtime library version.)

Answer (score 2):

Downloaded the scala libraries from http://scala-lang.org/download/ and added the scala-library.jar to the project, error resolved!

Answer (score -1):

Delete the unneccessary `jar` files and keep exact version `jar` file. It worked for me.

Comment: Id details don't belong in the answer, you can change your username and location in your personal settings, also, caps are not needed.